# How to build hello world recipe in yocto

Tags: c, cross-compiling, yocto, bitbake, openembedded

1. C file

```
    int main() {
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
    return 0;
    }
```

2. helloworld.bb

```
DESCRIPTION = "Recipe created by bitbake-layers"
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/MIT;md5=0835ade698e0bcf8506ecda2f7b4f302"


SRC_URI = "file://${BSPDIR}/poky/build-microchip/my_layer/recipes-example/helloworld/helloworld/helloworld.c"

S = "/home/user/my_dir/poky/build-microchip/conf"

do_compile() {
        ${CC} helloworld.c  -o helloworld
}

do_install() {
        install -d ${D}${bindir}
        install -m 0755 helloworld ${D}${bindir}
}
```

3. Run Command

bitbake helloworld

**ERROR**
error in do_compile() block helloworld.c file not found

1. File Tree

```
    build-microchip/my_layer/recipes-examples/
    └── helloworld
        ├── helloworld
        │   └── helloworld.c
        └── helloworld.bb
```

2 directories, 2 files

Comment: Are you sure about the `${BSPDIR}/poky/build-microchip/my_layer/recipes-example/helloworld/helloworld/helloworld.c`? Mainly on `${BSPDIR}`? Usually files are under a files subdirectory where bb file is placed.

Comment: Just to doublecheck, what is the name of the "C file" you are showing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's rather unusual to have absolute paths in `SRC_URI`.

For a recipe called `helloworld_0.1.bb` located at `build-microchip/my_layer/recipes-examples/helloworld/`, `SRC_URI` content is looked up for by default (and in order) in one of the following directories (`FILESPATH`[1]) for your recipe:

1. `build-microchip/my_layer/recipes-examples/helloworld/helloworld-0.1`
2. `build-microchip/my_layer/recipes-examples/helloworld/helloworld`
3. `build-microchip/my_layer/recipes-examples/helloworld/files`

So, you actually do NOT need to pass any of those directory names, Yocto will find it by itself. You just pass to `SRC_URI` the path **relative** to one of the aforementioned paths.

If you want to use files outside of the current directory of the recipe, usually `externalsrc` class has to be inherited (and it's usually not a good idea to do such a thing). Except in the case of bbappends where you add another path to the list with `FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/<otherdir>"` which puts `${THISDIR}/<otherdir>` at the first place in the above list.

Please note that there can be one more layer of "abstraction" with the content of `FILESOVERRIDES`[2]. In case of doubt, always look at log.do_fetch in the `WORKDIR` of your recipe, it will give you all the paths traversed to find a file and in which order they're traversed.

`SRC_URI = "file://helloworld.c"` should be fine for you.

I'm pretty much sure `S` is not set to what Yocto is expecting. `S`[3] is the directory where the sources are for Yocto after the `do_unpack` task. It is a temporary directory setup by Yocto. It usually starts with `${WORKDIR}` which is the temp directory for a given recipe. In the case of local sources only, set `S = "${WORKDIR}"` because local files from `SRC_URI` (those starting with `file://`) are put in `${WORKDIR}` by the fetcher. By default it is set to `${WORKDIR}/<recipename-recipeversion>`.

`do_compile` task runs in `B` which is by default set to `${S}`, incorrectly set in the recipe. That is why your file couldn't be found.[4]

## TL;DR:

```
SRC_URI = "file://helloworld.c"
S = "${WORKDIR}"
```

[1] https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#var-FILESPATH

[2] https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#var-FILESOVERRIDES

[3] https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#var-S

[4] https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#ref-tasks-compile

Answer (score 0):

You could put .c file in a subfolder of you recipe like

```
sources/poky/build-microchip/my_layer/recipes-example
└── helloworld
    ├── files
    │   └── helloworld.c
    └── helloworld.bb
```

and modify the recipe

```
SRC_URI = "file://helloworld.c"
```

When invoked for a recipe, `Bitbake` has a list of default folders where to look for files, e.g. `files` subdir.

In this way the recipe is it portable and you are sure that files can be found.

Comment: How does this solve the problem? Why is OPs longer path not possible?

Comment: @Yunnosch Because of OP put the file under a subdir with the same name of the recipe, not in a files subdir...And why use a full path when bitbake look in the files subdir embedded? At least, in the way I wrote, it is more portable.

Comment: Please [edit] to put that explanation into the answer itself, instead of  hiding it in the comments down here. Also, please consider to elaborate your explanation.

Comment: Thanks. i will try it

Comment: Thanks for explaining why your (better and portable) solution works. But what is the explanation why OPs does not work?

Comment: @Yunnosch Ok: I see, pedantic mode ON. I think it is doing something wrong with it paths. I'm not looking for point, I'm trying to help OP. If it is the right solution I will complete the answer or , if wrong, I'll delete it. It is too long to write it down in a comment...

Comment: Yes, pendantic mode is good for writing answers. Detailed explanations make it easier to decide (for upvoting purposes) whether an answer is good and make it more likely that the OP understands whether/how the answer is helpful specifically for the OP. So, stay in pedantic mode, it will make for a more appreciable contribution to StackOverflow and serve your personal goal of helping OP. Waiting for OP to confirm that the answer is helpful before writing a good explanation does not help either purpose. And please copy the explanations you have to the answer. Visible explanations are better.

Comment: @LPs helloworld is perfectly fine as a subdir. I actually advocate pretty heavily on having recipe name as subdir instead of files.
Subdirs are checked in the following order: recipename-recipeversion, recipename, files. http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta/classes/base.bbclass#n82